# If a real square matrix has only real eigenvalues, is it symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If a real square matrix has only real eigenvalues, is it symmetric?

I know that a real symmetric matrix has only real eigenvalues, but I'm wondering if the counter implication follows.

Comment: It's true only for normal matrices.

Comment: @chaohuang normal matrices?

Comment: [Normal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try checking on some arbitrarily chosen $2\times 2$ matrices? Pretty soon you'll find one with only real eigenvalues that is not symmetric.

Hint: Modify the identity matrix at just one place.

Answer (score 1):

No, $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ has real egenvalues, but is not symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.

Eg. $\begin{pmatrix}
1& 2\\
0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

No. For any $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&1\\0&\lambda\end{pmatrix}$ has real eigenvalues ($\lambda$) and is not symmetric. Furthermore, it is a Jordan block that is *not* similar to any symmetric matrix.